# Connecting to EC2 Amazon using iTerm and .pub-file

Tags: ssh, keychain, aws

How can I setup my iTerm to connect my amazon server using the .pem file I have been given.

When I try `ssh PUBLIC-DNS` it returns `Permission denied (publickey).`.

**EDIT**

I have now tried the following without log, including a debug log:

```
Marks-MacBook-Air:.ssh mark$ ssh -i s1.pem -v ubuntu@**********.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ************.amazonaws.com [***.***.***.***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file s1.pem type -1
debug1: identity file s1.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
debug1: Host '**************.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mark/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mark/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: s1.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please note that I have removed the following informations `SERVER IP`, `PUBLIC DNS` and `RSA KEY`

Comment: The default user for EC2 instances depends on the source of the AMI you're using to spawn the instance. Can you please provide a link to the AMI you're starting your instance from? FWIW Amazon usually uses `ec2-user` as the default user, not `ubuntu`.

Comment: The default user for ubuntu on `ec2` is `ubuntu`. It says on thir documentation page. But even with the user `ec2-user` it still returns `Permission denied (publickey).`.

Comment: I noticed in my debugging process that it says `debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mark/.ssh/id_rsa`, which is not the key for this server, but is used for another server that my job helped me configure. So why does it tries to use this RSA key?

Comment: Have a look for `/Users/mark/.ssh/id_rsa` in your `/Users/mark/.ssh/config` file - it's possible that some other directive is setting that as the identity file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh -i /path/to/keypair.pem user@host` should do it.

Comment: I have now tried the above without luck. But have posted a log above in my answer.

Comment: You might also need to `chmod 400 /path/to/keypair.pem`

Comment: Already did this since I before got the error `Permissions 0666 for 's1.pem' are too open.`. Any other ideas?